# Cannot add an Event Listener to an html element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add simple mouse event to an html element but I keep getting the above error and I dont know why.

Can anyone help me. I just want the html element to change its color when the mouse hovers it. It shouldn´t be so difficult. Maybe it has to do that I am writing on top of the Bootstraps file structure and something is going wrong there.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("barra2");

a.addEventListener("click", handlemouse);

function handlemouse() {
  document.getElementById("barra2").style.color = "#7B3FBF";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="artbox">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p class="h-100 d-inline-block" ; id="barra1"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="h-100 d-inline-block" ; id="barra2">b2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="h-100 d-inline-block gradient" ; id="barra3"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="h-100 d-inline-block gradient" ; id="barra4"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p class="h-100 d-inline-block gradient" ; id="barra5"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `<p class="h-100 d-inline-block" ; id="barra2">b2</p>` may not be valid HTML -- what's that semi-colon doing in there?  Also, where are you executing your Javascript code, above, or below, the HTML.  If above, and not doing it inside some framework's `ready` functionality (or even just vanilla Javascript's setTimeout/0) then the DOM element you're looking for won't be available

Comment: You want to change the color on hover or on click ? Your eventListener is working as it should works.

Comment: You are probably using an old version of IE? this code works fine in modern browsers.

Comment: Please specify which browser and version this error occurs in.

Comment: @Reflective - an early version of IE would say something like `a.addEventListener is not a function` - I think the error is that the error message is being misreported (perhaps a translation issue?) in the question

Comment: You can expect everything from IE but you might be right about that the error is not correctly referred.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 framework. The css stuff i added it at the end of the bootstrap.css file...  and for the js code i created a new file main.js and linked to it from the index like this.

Comment: i have edited the code, i am pretty sure i am using the framework the wrong way...

Comment: The code you've provided works. You need a [mcve] **of the problem**